# object speed is to slow although it works well when jumping [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 3d game following a tutorial

the instructor does not use the normal rigidbody component ,instead it use the characterController component and update the characterController.move vector3 motion value using the horizontal ,vertical ,jump input.

to simulate the gravity of the rigidbody manually by updating it over the time .

this works well for jumping but when falling from high place the falling is instantaneous within almost no time (no natural appearance)
the second issue that once I move the player is lifted up in the y direction abnormally.

here is the code I used :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal, vertical;
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float ySpeed;
    public float allowedPeriod;
    private float? lastTimeGround,lastTimeButtonPressed;
 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //using the coyota principle allow the user to jump even after leaving the ground
        // if the time period between the last time it was on ground 
        //then if the jump button was pressed allow the jump i.e give the yspeed a value
        //
        if (controller.isGrounded)
            lastTimeGround = Time.time;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            lastTimeButtonPressed = Time.time;
      //if the 
        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, ySpeed, vertical);
        if (Time.time - lastTimeGround < allowedPeriod)
        {

            if (Time.time - lastTimeButtonPressed < allowedPeriod)
            {
                ySpeed = 2f;
                lastTimeGround = null;
                lastTimeButtonPressed = null;

            }
        }
     
        //to make the player get down with the simulation of gravity
        // we will reduce the y value by gravity over the frame time  remember :Physics.garvity.y=-9.81
        if(transform.position.y>0.05f)
            ySpeed += Physics.gravity.y*Time.deltaTime*0.5f;
     
        controller.Move(movementDirection*Time.deltaTime*5.0f);
        movementDirection.Normalize();
        Debug.Log(movementDirection);
        //create a new quaternion direction
        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            movementDirection.y = 0;
            Quaternion destination = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, destination, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        }

    }
}
```

could you highlight to me what is wrong with my code?